# Importing .ts or .tsx files in React project

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Looking for advice about the proper setup for importing .tsx or .ts files in my React project. I'm currently converting .js files to .tsx and just using `@ts-ignore` for my imports, but I would like to configure everything correctly. Any suggestions?

Here is my ts-config file:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "esnext",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- If this is a **new project** (or your **first time** using the combination of React and Typescript), then I wouldn't configure it yourself, but instead use the [typescript template for Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/): `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`
- If this is an **existing project** that you're adding typescript to, then I'd check out the official documentation on [Adding Typescript to a Project](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html#adding-typescript-to-a-project)
- If you're searching for **more info** regarding the **tsconfig** in general, see the typescript documentation: [What is a tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). This page also includes [TSConfig Bases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#tsconfig-bases) that you can extend from.
- If you're looking for **sensible defaults** to expand your already configured app with, then consider creating a dummy Create React App with typescript and comparing your config files. The base configuration is very good.

Bonus: [React TypeScript Cheatsheets](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/) might be worth looking into as well. It has a page on [Migrating (to Typescript)](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/migration/intro)